# Paper Icon Buttons not rendering in Firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, polymer, web-component

I have a problem with paper icon buttons not rendering in firefox (latest update). In chrome the icons render perfectly. I've narrowed the problem down to any icons which have an external source.

```
<paper-icon-button icon="favorite" title="heart"></paper-icon-button>
<paper-icon-button src="https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/modules/logos_page/Octocat.png" alt="octocat" title="octocat"></paper-icon-button>
```

adding both lines to my project, the first one renders correctly but the second one does not. (Both render in chrome)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix HTTPS and HTTP assets without issue.  Either access your page over HTTPS, or change the second button src protocol to HTTP.

Unfortunately, it looks like github is going to kick you over to HTTPS regardless.

Realted: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/fixing-mixed-content

Comment: this does not render either (works in chrome though)  `<paper-icon-button src="assets/icons/cat.png" alt="octocat" title="octocat"></paper-icon-button>`